# Can the Composite (from the Composite Pattern) have an isLeaf() method?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, composite

Is there a reason the *Composite* should not have an `isLeaf()` method?

(Since the point of this pattern is (if I'm not wrong) to be able to use both the *Leaf* and the *Composite* as the same thing, without differentiating?)

Or is it absolutely OK if I can still use them both as if they were the same thing, **BUT** also find out which is which if I want to?

Answer (score 0):

One of the debated questions about Composite is how to handle getChildren() in the leaf class. If you are using an interface, you can have it in the shared interface, and then in the leaf class, throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

You can also use Visitor to have different handling for different node types, so the classic filesystem where the Folder/File Composite is the core of it, you could do a Visitor that would make it easy to provide special actions for the different types (or only handle specific types).

Do you have a plan for how you would use it? Maybe the specific case would be a better way to deem the value of the method.

Answer (score 0):

It's also my understanding that the essence of this pattern is that you should not need to know the actual type you have a reference to as you're iterating over the items. However, I've used the pattern and included attempts to cast to a specific type, effectively the same as differentiating with isLeaf. This clearly devalues polymorphism and violates the OCP, however it worked appropriately in that situation.

I view design patterns as handrails, not handcuffs.